# SVN Issue:Commit blocked by pre-commit hook(exit code 1) with output

Tags: svn

I got the error:

> Commit blocked by pre-commit hook(exit code 1) with output:The length of the   'log' message is less than 20 characters

If i create a new repository and uploading the file is working fine. Problem is with old repository.

What would be the issue?

Comment: Adding a pre-commit hook isn't standard issue SVN.  Ask who added it.  Could you try adding a comment with more than 20 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Contact the administrator of the Subversion server and ask him. He set the hook script that denies commits with empty log messages and it's a wise decision.

If you are the server administrator, read the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) prior to performing any maintenance tasks on the server.